# Adding a key to the permitted params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this:

```
  def some_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :pass)
```

These params are under the key "person" in "params". How can I add a key from the top level of "params" to the list of permitted params? In total it should result into 3 keys of permitted params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add other call to the method require like:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  key1: 1,
  person: {
    name: 'Francesco',
    pass: 'pass'
  }
})
params.permit(:key1, {:person => [:name,  :pass]})
```

Check the docs at: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#require-multiple-parameters

> ### Require Multiple Parameters
>
> If you want to make sure that multiple keys are present in a params
>   hash, you can call the method twice:
>
> ```
> params.require(:token)
> params.require(:post).permit(:title)
> ```

Comment: a key from the top level of "params"

Comment: "require" requires a parent hash key, doesn't it?

Comment: could you show the hash that you want to allow? this way is easier to see what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: {a => 1, my_key => 2, c => 3, person => {name: 4, pass: 5}}

Comment: I want to allow all the keys under person and my_key

Comment: use `params.permit(:a)` then you can use `params[:a]`

Comment: yeah, but how to put them in the same level so that there're no nested keys? I need it to be able to pass "person_params" to Person.create()

Comment: the param's are parsed according to the the request, how param's are structured is something the form or client do, you need to check that other part